# Lumen 5.4 Helper class not available globally

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I have created Helper function in

lumen\app\Helpers\Helpers.php

and added

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('config_path'))
{
        /**
        * Return the path to config files
        * @param null $path
        * @return string
        */
        function config_path($path=null)
        {
                return app()->getConfigurationPath(rtrim($path, ".php"));
        }
}
```

in compoer.json

```
,
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helpers.php"
    ],
```

then ran

```
composer dump-autoload -o
composer dump-autoload
```

after that if try to call in web.php

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {


  echo config_path();


});
```

Getting following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function config_path() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\lumen\routes\web.php on line 17
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `web.php` is executed before `Helpers.php`. The best thing you can do is to put any logic into the Controller, Models etc and keep routes only in `web.php`.

If you don't care about this, you can `require()` helpers file in `index.php`, but again, it's a bad practice.

Comment: @Alexey.Ya its bad but i dont know why its not working in lumen.Same think is working fine in laravel

Comment: @Alexey.This helper i am using for jwt etc

Comment: With laravel itself, I think it is working fine but for Lumen, I never had to have helpers because of a small project.

If Lumen has a bootstrap file like Laravel, require_once your helpers there and not in the public/index.php :/

Comment: @everytimeicob.ya i have added in bootstrap app.php but 
D:\xampp\htdocs\lumen>php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "vendor" namespace. not working

Comment: @vision this is another problem

Comment: ya i agree .need to know why its not working autolaod files .thanks